# spring boot starter data jpa is registering unnecessary hibernate dialect

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have Spring boot application with `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency and application.properties file configured to point to database, the application is working fine but in the `catalina.out` file I see that the application is registering all the dialects. How can I remove the loading of all dialects except the one I'm using.

Section of `catalina.out` file with Registering dialects logs.

```
TRACE   2018-03-15 20:10:45,726 [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl [] - Registering named strategy selector [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] : [Interbase] -> [org.hibernate.dialect.InterbaseDialect]
TRACE   2018-03-15 20:10:45,727 [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl [] - Registering named strategy selector [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] : [JDataStore] -> [org.hibernate.dialect.JDataStoreDialect]
TRACE   2018-03-15 20:10:45,728 [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl [] - Registering named strategy selector [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] : [Mckoi] -> [org.hibernate.dialect.MckoiDialect]
TRACE   2018-03-15 20:10:45,738 [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl [] - Registering named strategy selector [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] : [MimerSQL] -> [org.hibernate.dialect.MimerSQLDialect]
TRACE   2018-03-15 20:10:45,741 [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl [] - Registering named strategy selector [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] : [MySQL5] -> [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect]
TRACE   2018-03-15 20:10:45,742 [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl [] - Registering named strategy selector [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] : [MySQL5InnoDB] -> [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect]
TRACE   2018-03-15 20:10:45,743 [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl [] - Registering named strategy selector [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] : [MySQL57InnoDB] -> [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57InnoDBDialect]
TRACE   2018-03-15 20:10:45,746 [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl [] - Registering named strategy selector [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] : [Oracle8i] -> [org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle8iDialect]
TRACE   2018-03-15 20:10:45,747 [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl [] - Registering named strategy selector [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] : [Oracle9i] -> [org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect]
TRACE   2018-03-15 20:10:45,748 [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl [] - Registering named strategy selector [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] : [Oracle10g] -> [org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect]
... and more
```

application.properties file

```
# Database information
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/mm
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect

# things I tried to remove registering of unnecessary dialects
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
```

Comment: remove `properties` from `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect`

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't work.

Comment: can you post how you are doing database configuration, or you just kept this properties file in the resources folder?

Comment: @Vishrant I'm just using this properties file and using JdbcTemplate object for database calls.

Comment: This is weird, can you check this repository https://github.com/netgloo/spring-boot-samples/tree/master/spring-boot-mysql-springdatajpa-hibernate and try to compare with your implementation.

Comment: please share your latest findings.

Comment: @Vishrant, no update, I just let it go.

Comment: is it feasible to share source code of you application?

Comment: @Vishrant, I can't, but I created a sample spring boot application with dependencies spring-boot-starter-log4j  and spring-boot-starter-data-jpa. Created HelloWorld controller with Get method and log4j.properties file.

Comment: log4j.properties file:

log4j.rootLogger=TRACE,ConsoleAppender

log4j.logger.org.springframework=WARN
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.id.factory=WARN
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.resource=ERROR

log4j.appender.ConsoleAppender=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.ConsoleAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ConsoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%-7p %d [%t] %c [%X{userName}] - %m%n

And in application.properties file please add the DB information shown above.

Comment: are you getting same issue in your sample project? your last comment did not helped me to identify the issue.

Comment: Yes, getting same problem. Last comment is log4j properties file configuration. You can copy it into your sample project and move anything that starts with log4j to new line,